# PM2 port number express app

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Application configuration section
   * http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
   */
  apps : [

    // First application
    {
      name      : 'cms_stage',
      script    : 'www',
      env: {
        COMMON_VARIABLE: 'true',
        PORT: 3001,
        NODE_ENV: 'staging'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have an express app when i start with `PORT=3001 node www`, it works. But with pm2 above config it doesn't. pm2 show started but it is not listening to 3001

I tried running `PORT=3001 pm2 start cms_stage`, `pm2 start cms_stage` and `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`.

reading port number like this `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)` in app.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

worked after killing pm2 with `pm2 kill`

Comment: You can mark your own answers as accepted, if the problem is resolved and you feel the question & answer will be useful to future readers, go ahead and mark it as accepted. If this is more a case of "problem no longer reproducible", you might also want to consider deleting question & answer.